# How to write in file the result of query in C#. For example (Name salary)

Tags: c#, sql

I need to write in .doc file the result of query in C#
     Code

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id,Name,Price FROM [Products] WHERE [Id]=@Id ", sqlConnection);
While (await sqlReader.ReadAsync()){
    listBox3.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(sqlReader["id"]) + "  " + 
    Convert.ToString(sqlReader["Name"]) + "  " + (1 + ((readSearch1 - f) * 1.2) / f));
}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/shps951023/75033925d7c64037dfb878ab9042eb91

Comment: Minor point: this won't even compile as written, due to `While` incorrectly being capitalized.

Comment: This isn't valid C# or SQL. I don't see anything about a .doc file. And that's not how to add items to a ListBox control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Docx library to do this.
https://cathalscorner.blogspot.com/search?q=create

```
 // Create a new document.
using (DocX document = DocX.Create("Test.docx"))
{
    // Create a new Paragraph with the text "Hello World".
    Paragraph p = document.InsertParagraph("Hello World.");

    // Make this Paragraph flow right to left. Default is left to right.
    p.Direction = Direction.RightToLeft;

    // Save all changes made to this document.
    document.Save();
}
```